# How to respond to a Yes / No command prompt via Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm running a :

```
- command: vsx update-software ...
```

command to perform an update on a host, the command requests to enter "y" to go ahead with its exection.
Will the command be executed with "yes" by default or should I add an Ansdible directive to respond with "yes" ? if so which directive please ?

Comment: Can you try `yes | vsx update-software` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `expect` module,

```
- name: Upgrading Software
  expect:
    command: vsx update-software
    responses:
      'First Question in the prompt' : 'y'
      'Second Question in the prompt' : 'y'
```

More on `expect` can be found [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html).

Comment: Answering "Y" sends another prompt that I should respond also with "Y" to. Should I add the other prompt like : `'Question 2 in the prompt' : 'y'` ?

Comment: You can add as many responses as it is required to it. Updated the answer

Comment: Should the space before ':' be removed or is it okay ?

Comment: It is a dictionary, space surrounding the `:` should not cause errors. Try skipping the space and see if it works. Unable to test and confirm at the moment.